# Actionscript Screen Idle

Tags: actionscript-3, timeout, screen, python-idle

I made a small flash program to help me with my workouts but because of the length the computer screen goes idle. It looks like there is a solution for this on android but is there one just for regular flash programs?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an AIR app, to disable screen timeout set:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
```

If this is Flash running in a browser, I do not believe it is possible.